# How to determine an EventHandler's thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling, begininvoke

I have an event, which is normally raised asynchronously, like this:

```
foreach (EventHandler eventHandler in Event.GetInvocationList())
{
   eventHandler.BeginInvoke(sender, e, EndRaiseEvent, eventHandler);
}
```

Now there might also be listeners who are on the same thread as the one which is raising the event, and in that case I want the event to be raised synchronous (without BeginInvoke), but how do I differentiate those in the InvocationList?

Comment: The phrase "listeners are on different threads" is meaningless.  Using BeginInvoke() like this will certainly not ever make anybody happy, there is no point to it.  You can only ever hope that an event handler runs on a specific thread if that thread is the UI thread of a program.  You'd use Dispatcher.Invoke or Control.Invoke.  And ought to be used in the event handler itself.

Comment: @HansPassant The reason for BeginInvoke is to let my class continue processing data without being blocked (or deadlocked) by slow listeners?

Comment: Objects in .NET are free threaded, which is why @HansPassant states that the statement "listeners are on different threads".  Work can be done on separate threads, but objects are not tied to threads (unless you're working with COM objects).

Comment: @KevinS The procedure that raises the event holds locks on several object. For event-listeners who run on the "same thread" these locks are no problem, but event-listeners who run on "another tread' will never be able to process the event because of those locks, causing a deadlock. So even though HansPassant is technically correct, I dont know how to explain it simpler.

Comment: It sounds like you should customize the event by having the clients sign up with an interface that exposes which type of client it is. This isn't a .NET event, but I don't think the functionality you are looking for is built in. UI controls expose the ability to determine if Invoke is necessary, but events do not.

Comment: @KevinS Thats exactly how I had set it up already, each event-subscriber sets a flag wether it wants to be called back using Invoke or BeginInvoke. I just wanted to see if it was possible to remove the flags, and decide automaticly based on the data in GetInvocationList(). Because the problem with the manual flags is that everytime I make code changes relating to threading, I have to make sure every flag is still correct. Which is stupid, because I should be able to determine the flag based on thread-id or something.

Comment: So you appear to be logically assigning objects to a specific thread. Are the objects created on that thread? You could have them grab the Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId on creation. If you have some sort of manager that assigns them to threads you could pass the ID as part of the constructor. Your general design sounds like one that is prone to deadlocks, but I'm positive i don't really understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to. There is not meaning of other listeners running on "a different thread". When an event is raised, if you are registered to it then it dosen't matter on what thread it was raised on, you will be called.

Comment: I know that. Its just that I want to avoid BeginInvoke for event listeners that don't need it. Not only to save on performance, but also because Im calling BeginInvoke so the objects will be lock-free when the listener starts processing, and for event-listeners who run in the same thread thats not necessary.

Comment: Not really understanding the "locks free" statement. Are you updating mutual state?

Comment: Im raising the event from a function that locks (c# lock statement) an object the eventhandlers might need access to.